# Oracle regexp_substr with 4 parameters to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, regexp-replace

I'm porting from Oracle to Postgres, I have a query in Oracle where I have `regexp_substr` in the select clause with 4 parameters. If `regexp_substr` has just 2 parameters (string and matching pattern), I could go with `regexp_matches` in Postgres. But when there are 4 parameters(string, matching pattern, starting position, nth occurrence), I'm not able to find an alternative.

Can someone help on converting it to Postgres? Thanks for helping !

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** your question and show us the current code and some sample data along with it to demonstrate what it does?

Comment: This has been asked [a lot of times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+regexp_substr) probably one of those answers is what you are looking for

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thank you. I could use split_part function in Postgres for this case.